# Elements count in list

Tags: coq

I am dividing n1 number of elements in natural list l1 and n2 in l2. During executing this step I need to prove below lemma. I struct here. Here is code

```
Lemma g_list_max n l : In n l -> n <= list_max l.
Proof.
destruct l as [ | a l'].
 simpl. contradiction.
unfold list_max.  intros. simpl in *.
destruct H. rewrite  H.
```

Comment: Can you give more details as to why you are stuck? How would you prove it on paper? Perhaps by induction?

Comment: Yes, by induction . With the help of these two lemmas                      
 Lemma g_in n l : In (list-max l) (n :: l).
Lemma max_grt n l : forall c, In c (n :: l) -> c <= (list-max l).

Comment: Lemma m_In : forall (l : list nat) (n : nat),
forall e, In e l -> 
e <= list_max l.
Proof.
intros. apply (Forall_forall (fun k : nat => k <= (list_max l)) l).
apply (list_max_le l (list_max l)). auto. apply H.
Qed.

Answer (score 0):

The number of elements in a list `l` is given by `length l`.
I encourage you to `Search length.` to know more about them or simply have a look at the [`List` module of the standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html).

Comment: I have edited the question. Might be it is more clear now.